# Remove small current on desktop PC casing

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I have an i7 desktop PC.I can feel that there is a small current on the casing. So is that normal or what will happen due to this in the future? How to remove this current on the casing?

`your power cord doesn't have the third wire` - It has it and all are very good condition. i.e new items.

`your house/office doesn't have a proper grounding installation`- My house has proper grounding installation. i.e. put the earth wire in the ground. i.e. If there is lighting then our house's tip switch automatically off to save the electric items in the house.

`buying a voltage stabilizer or a UPS` - I have a UPS and I supplied the power to PC through UPS.

***This is the power code which I use with the PC:***

[image]

***This is my PC and UPS setup:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be normal depending if your house has wiring that is not properly grounded.  It is easily solved by properly grounding your case.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I didn't get you? We have proper electrical wiring system in my house and etc. i.e. grounded eath wire and etc. So what should I do here?

Comment: @Ramhound I have put my desktop PC casing on the wood table.

Comment: If the socket was providing a proper ground then you would not feel a small current when you touched your case.  How you solve it depends on specific facts.  If you are in a part of the world, where this type of thing is common, you ground your case using a UPS.  If you are in a part of the world, where it's supposed to already be grounded, you call a qualified electrician to solve a much larger issue then an improperly ground case.  You have provided zero details to determine which solution would be best for you.

Comment: @Ramhound Please see the updated post.

Comment: Even with your information, it does not change the fact.  Your case is not properly grounded.  You can purchase a grounding plug, that you could clip to the side of the case, should be safe to do this, provided the PSU is connected to the same ground source.

Comment: @Ramhound Still not clear what are you telling. Can you show me some image or url of your solution? i.e. `You can purchase a grounding plug, that you could clip to the side of the case`

Comment: @Ramhound I have added the photo. Are you telling about this? i.e. power code?

Comment: My suggestion is a life hack, and it only works, if you have a valid working earth ground (which isn't the case) since your case has an electrical charge.

Comment: Can you provide an image of how your power supply plugs in on your computer side?  Also, us the olug feeding your UPS grounded?  If these are OK there is probably a fault with your PSU - ie it is not grounded correctly, ir the grounding in the UPS does nit touch the case.

Comment: @davidgo You can see the complete setup on my post now.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that your computer is not grounded.

Either:
a) your power cord doesn't have a third wire (or the plug is broken).
or b) your house/office doesn't have a proper grounding installation.

If the first is the case, changing cords should help. Otherwise, you should check with an electrician to review your installation.

Another way you can protect your computer, is by buying a voltage stabilizer or an UPS.

If you don't do anything, eventually your computer will have a power surge, which can damage internal components. If that damages your hard drive, you'll lose all your info.

Comment: `your power cord doesn't have the third wire` - It has it and all are very good condition. i.e new items. `your house/office doesn't have a proper grounding installation`- My house has proper grounding installation. i.e. put the earth wire in the ground. i.e. If there is lighting then our house's tip switch automatically off to save the electric items in the house.   `buying a voltage stabilizer or a UPS` - I have a UPS and I supplied the power to PC through UPS. So then?

Comment: Then maybe your UPS is defective? Have you tried without it?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have a brand new Prolink UPS and it is working fine. http://desktop.lk/product/prolink-650va-ups-2y/

Comment: A possibility is that you do have an electric ground well, however it may need maintenance. Because it uses gel (Thor-Gel for example), it requires to be recharged at least once a year, and be measured to be under 10 ohms in resistance. An electrical technician can check it out and diagnose it better.

Comment: Oh.. We don't have such a thing. Can you provide me a good link for reading it more? We have just a grounded earth wire somewhere in the garden. That is it.

Comment: That may be it. I'll point you to the old trusted Wikipedia if you want further research on the matter. I do recommend you hire an specialist to look over your installation and give you a proper recommendation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system

Comment: Conclusion: No proper ground is the problem after all. That's why a qualified professional is needed, not someone that thinks a wire in the ground is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Some power supply have this issue...With switching power supplies it's normal for some very low amount of AC current to leak into the ground wire (the third wire of the power connector) which is also connected to all the metal parts of your computer (the metal case of your power supply and therefore the metal case of your power supply since the psu is screwed to the case and metal touches metal)

Could very well be that the PSU may not pass a Hi-Pot test.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).